# MySQL Workbench Manage Server Instances

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I successfully installed MySQL server (I can connect to it manually through the MySQL shell). When I try to establish a connection through MySQL Workbench, the test connection goes through as well. But when I try to view the server's info or interact with the server, an error message pops up that says, "Current profile has no WMI enabled." I have searched for a solution to this problem, and found a few threads like this one: https://www.quora.com/MySQL-Workbench-How-can-I-solve-the-Current-Profile-Has-no-WMI-enable-error-message. However, I just can't find the 'Manage Server Instances' dialog or button anywhere. I am running workbench version 6.3. If anyone has run into this problem then I would appreciate a workaround.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's unusual that you get that error again. I haven't heard since years of such a problem. Anyway, the solution is still to configure the connection properly. That "configure server instances" link is very old (from WB 5.x). Instead look for the connection editor (titled: Manage Server Connections). You can open the dialog either via the main menu or the small wrench button on the homescreen:

[image]